# How to display polygons that are within a specific range (circle) using Leaflet

Tags: mongodb, leaflet, polygon, openstreetmap, geometry

I am trying find a solution on how to display polygons that are only within a specific range, a circle with radius using leaflet.

[Polygons screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKV5P.jpg)

Before, I have ask for help regarding on the display of points within a specific range but this time, since a polygon have many nodes/coordinates, i don't have any idea of how it can be done for polygons; a foreach statement?

Any solution? Thanks for the help!

[Similar problem solved for displaying points within a specific range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28742112/unable-to-display-only-the-points-within-a-specific-range-circle-using-the-ge)

Comment: Loop them? If you have all the main points, just change them. If you want it twice the size center out, you multiply all sides (from center point) by 1.5. If you just want it twice as large, multiply everything by 2. (Coords I mean.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using MongoDB, the best solution here is (if that's possible), to handle this in the database. Put `2dsphere` indexes on your document's `loc` field and use a `$geoWithin` query in combination with `$centerSphere`:

> The following example queries grid coordinates and returns all documents within a 10 mile radius of longitude 88 W and latitude 30 N. The query converts the distance to radians by dividing by the approximate radius of the earth, 3959 miles:

```
db.places.find( {
    loc: { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [ [ -88, 30 ], 10/3959 ] } }
} )
```

2dsphere reference: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/

$geoWithin reference: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/

$centerSphere reference: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/centerSphere/

If you really want to do this clientside (which i absolutely wouldn't recommend) and you don't want to build your on solution (which is possible) you could take a look at GeoScript.

GeoScript's `geom.Geometry()` class has a `contains` method:

> Tests if this geometry contains the other geometry (without boundaries touching).

Geom.geometry reference: http://geoscript.org/js/api/geom/geometry.html

**EDIT**: Here's the pure JS/Leaflet solution as requested in the comments, this is quick-n-dirty, but it should work. Here the `containsPolygon` method returns true when all of the polygon's points are within the circle:

```
L.Circle.include({
    'containsPoint': function (latLng) {
        return this.getLatLng().distanceTo(latLng) < this.getRadius();
    },
    'containsPolygon': function (polygon) {
        var results = [];
        polygon.getLatLngs().forEach(function (latLng) {
            results.push(this.containsPoint(latLng));
        }, this);
        return (results.indexOf(false) === -1);
     }
});
```

Here's a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/JlFToy?p=preview

If you want to return true if one or more of the polygon's points are within the circle than you must change the return statement to this:

```
return (results.indexOf(true) !== -1);
```

Comment: Is there a leaflet solution similar to the point display one?

Comment: I wrote that answer, and one for polygons but i can't remember if it was on this site, can't find it anymore in my results. Got to check my archive.

Comment: Couldn't find it but hacked one simple solution together for you, check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, i will only be able to try it tomorrow at the university. I know that i have taken much of your time regarding this issue but I was wondering, how can we adapt the code to that if there is at least 1 node of the polygon inside the circle, the display message says "Polygon inside of the circle".

Comment: Added other return statement to my answer

Comment: yep, i implemented the code and it works fine. Thanks!!