# Error when using Circle getBounds() and contains()

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

I'm getting the error below when trying to run getBounds() and contains() with a Circle shape.

```
leaflet.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'layerPointToLatLng' of undefined
```

I'm able to use it with the other shapes, but the circle is being stubborn. I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28742112/unable-to-display-only-the-points-within-a-specific-range-circle-using-the-ge) from another question, but no success.

Here's the code I have for the polygon and rectangle shapes:

```
drawnLayers.eachLayer(function(l) {
  if (type == 'circle') {

    // console.log(l.getBounds().contains(layer.getBounds()));

  } else {
    if (l.getBounds().contains(layer.getBounds())) {
      isDonut = true;

      l._latlngs.push(layer.getLatLngs());
      l.redraw();

      $('#map-info').append("<br>New Polygon: <pre>" +
        JSON.stringify(l.getLatLngs(), null, 2) + '</pre>');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: See https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4978

Answer (score 0):

```
l.getBounds().contains(layer.getBounds())
```

`getBounds()` is a method specific only to [polyline](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polyline-getbounds)/[polygon](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polygon-getbounds)/[rectangle](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#rectangle-getbounds) in leaflet 0.7.x

It was added to circle shapes as of version 1.0.0 - see [leaflet reference versions](http://leafletjs.com/reference-versions.html)

To solve the problem you have 2 options

1. use some other methods for circles like `getRadius()` and compute by yourself if the shape contains your other shape
2. upgrade your leaflet library

Personally I would upgrade the leaflet library to 1.0.3 (which I did very easy and without any compatibility issues on my project)